# Convergence of a sequence of positive linear operators in bounded Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

1. Let T be an operator in bounded Hilbert space with $0\leq T \leq I_H$. Then for what $n \in N$ $T^{n+1}\leq T^n$.
2. Now let {$T^n$} be a sequence in bounded Hilbert space such that $0\leq T^n\leq T^{n+1}\leq I_H$ for all $n\leq 1$. Show that for all $\xi \in H$,  {$T^n\xi$} is a Cauchy sequence. Also, there is a positive linear operator T such that $0\leq T \leq I_H$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty }T^n\xi=T\xi$.

Here is my try for the first question:

1.
We prove by induction that for all $n\geq 1$:

+) n=1, $T^2\leq T$ because

<$(T-T^2)\xi|\xi$> = <$T(1-T)\xi|\xi$> = <$(1-T)\xi|T\xi$> > 0

+) Suppose we have $T^{n+1}\leq T^{n}$ (or in other words <$T^n(1-T)\xi|\xi$> >0), we need to prove $T^{n+2}\leq T^{n+1}$. Indeed, we have:

<$(T^{n+1}-T^{n+2})\xi|\xi$> = <$TT^n(1-T)\xi|\xi$> = <$T^n(1-T)\xi|T\xi$> >0.

This completes the proof. What confused me is part 2, with the proof of part 1 then the sequence $T^n$ does not exist because n starts with 1. I hope to receive some comments or solution for these two problems. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#1. If $0 \le T \le I$, then
$$
    \langle T^{n+1}x,x\rangle=\langle TT^{n/2}x,T^{n/2}x\rangle \le \langle T^{n/2}x,T^{n/2}x\rangle=\langle T^n x,x\rangle,\;\;\; x\in\mathcal{H}.
$$
Therefore $T^{n+1} \le T^{n}$ for all $n=1,2,3,\cdots$.

#2. If $0 \le T \le T^2 \cdots \le T^n \le \cdots \le I$, then the following limits exist for all $x,y\in\mathcal{H}$ and $k=0,1,2,3$:
$$
         \lim_n \langle T^n(x+i^ky),x+i^ky\rangle.
$$
This is because $\langle T^n(x+i^ky),x+i^ky)\rangle$ is a real, non-negative, non-decreasing, bounded sequence in $n$. Therefore, the following limits exist for all $x,y\in\mathcal{H}$:
$$
        \lim_n \langle T^n x,y\rangle = \lim_n\frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=0}^{3}i^k\langle T^n (x+i^k y),x+i^k y\rangle
$$
Furthermore, $[x,y]=\lim_n\langle T^nx,y\rangle$ is a positive, bounded sesquilinear form. So there exists a bounded $0 \le S=S^* \le I$ such that $[x,y]=\langle Sx,y\rangle$. Then
$$
        \|(S-T^n)x\|^2 = \langle (S-T^n)x,(S-T^n)x\rangle \\
       \le \langle (S-T^n)x,x\rangle^{1/2}\langle (S-T^n)(S-T^n)x,(S-T^n)x\rangle^{1/2} \\
    \le \langle (S-T^n)x,x\rangle^{1/2}\langle (S-T^n)x,(S-T^n)x\rangle^{1/2}
$$
This gives
$$
            \|(S-T^n)x\| \le \langle (S-T^n)x,x\rangle^{1/2}
$$
Therefore $\lim_n T^nx = Sx$ holds for all $x$.

Comment: Thanks for your nice and short answer. Do you have any comment for part 2 assuming the sequence $T^n$ exists?

Comment: @ThuyNguyenthuynguyen : I've added that for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.